# How to get sysdate, time and timestamp from database using hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, datetime, jakarta-ee

In my application I need to get database date(`sysdate` in case of Oracle DB) and compare it with user input date (*`String` converted to `java.util.Date`*). From [this forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=961789) I got the following code which helps in the case of **Oracle** dialect.

```
public Date getDate() {
        Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select sysdate as mydate from dual");
        query.addScalar("mydate", Hibernate.TIMESTAMP);
        return (Date) query.uniqueResult();
    }
```

And from [this link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=974212&view=previous) got the following method which uses mapping file with formula.

```
<property name="currentDate" formula="(select sysdate from dual)"/>
```

Again this is specific to Oracle. I think using later method is more performance friendly, because we can get it from the same session, i.e no need of opening another session just for getting date.

I am looking for a generic solution to get date, time and timestamp from any DBMS using Hibernate. Using HQL is the preferred. Hope such a solution is available.

Comment: I did not think this question is that tough. 37 views and no answers yet!!!

Comment: Apparently it is - I'm looking for the same thing but ended using the SQLQuery method and sysdate as I found no alternative.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for .NET /C# solution, here is what worked for me:

```
// this works only with Oracle
public DateTime DbTimeStamp(ISession session)
{
    // Sample returned value = "12-OCT-11 01.05.54.365134000 AM -07:00"
    string sql = "SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL";
    ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql)
    .AddScalar("SYSTIMESTAMP", NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.DateTime);
    return query.UniqueResult<DateTime>();
}
```